# Morphism on Elliptic Curve to Intersection Point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I am working on a problem found in the Gathmann Algebraic Geometry notes (2019 edition) that I cannot figure out. I would appreciate any help that I could get on this. Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ be a the zero locus of a homogenous degree three polynomial. Define $U \subset X \times X$ as the set of all points $(a, b)$ such that $a, b \in X, a \neq b$. Then the line through $a, b$ intersects $X$ at one more unique point. Let $\psi \colon U \to X$ be the map sending $(a, b)$ to this third point. Show that $\psi$ is a morphism.

I am just not even sure where to start here. The question also asks to show that $U$ is open in $X \times X$. This is easy; it is the complement of the diagonal of $X$ which is closed as $X$ is a variety. Maybe that is supposed to help me find the answer, but I don't see how. I assume that I am supposed to show that
$$\psi(a, b) = (f_0(a, b), f_1(a, b), f_2(a, b))$$
for homogenous polynomials $f_0, f_1, f_2$ on $X \times X$ that don't mutually vanish on $U,$ but I don't know how to get to this or even really approach the problem. Perhaps the Segre embedding? If anyone could give me any tips or suggestions I would be grateful.